# Proving property of continuous random variables

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, probability-distributions, random-variables

In proving the following property for a continuous random variable with $X\ge0$: $\int_0^\infty P(X>x)dx=E[X]$ where $E[X]$ is expectation of X

$\int_0^\infty P(X>x)dx=\int_0^\infty 1\times(1-P(X\le x))dx=x(1-F_X(x))|_0^\infty+\int_0^\infty xf_X(x)dx = x(1-F_X(x))|_0^\infty+E[X]$

Where $F_X(x)$ is the distribution function of X and $f_X(x)$ is the pdf of X.

**Question**

How do I show that $x(1-F_X(x))|_0^\infty = 0$?
I have tried doing L'Hopital law i.e

$x(1-F_X(x))|_0^\infty=\lim_{n\to\infty}n(1-F_X(n))-0=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{1-F_X(n)}{\dfrac{1}{n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{f_X(n)}{n^{-2}}$ by applying L'Hopital in the last step, however im still stuck in showing that this limit goes to $0$.

PS: (I have used the fact that by FTC derivative of distribution function is equal to pdf )

Comment: As written, you can't conclude since you don't know how $F_X$ behave next to $x$...

Comment: To continue where you left of, then if we assume $X$ as finite variance, that is if $E[X^2]<\infty$, then $x^2 f_X(x) \rightarrow 0$ for  $x\rightarrow \infty$, since this is a neccessary condition for $\int_{0}^\infty x^2f_X(x) dx$ to converge.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For a non-negative absolutely continuous random variable $X$, with distribution $F$. Why is $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}t(1-F(t))=0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/985548/for-a-non-negative-absolutely-continuous-random-variable-x-with-distribution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that $E(X)=\int_0^\infty x\,dF(x)$ exists, you have $$\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_t^\infty x\,dF(x)= 0$$

Again,

\begin{align}
x(1-F(x))&=xP(X>x)
\\&=x\int_x^\infty dF(y)
\\&\le \int_x^\infty y\,dF(y)
\end{align}

So $\lim_{x\to\infty}x(1-F(x))\le 0$ and you already have $x(1-F(x))\ge 0$ for all $x\ge 0$.

Therefore a necessary condition for $E(X)$ to exist is that $$\lim_{x\to \infty} x(1-F(x))=0$$

Comment: why is $x\int_x^\infty dF(y)\le \int_x^\infty ydF(y)$?

Comment: @LucaIon $x\le y\implies \int_x^\infty x\,dF(y)\le \int_x^\infty y\,dF(y)$.

Comment: and why in our case $x\le y$?

Comment: In $\int_x^\infty dF(y)$, it is implied that $x\le y$.

Answer (score 1):

- Way 1 : Since $X$ is a continuous r.v., it has a density function, i.e. there is $f_X$ s.t. $\mathbb P(X\in A)=\int_A f_X(x)dx$for all $A$ measurable. Therefore

\begin{align*}\int_0^\infty  \mathbb P(X>x)dx&=\int_0^\infty \int_x^\infty f_X(y)dydx\\
&\underset{Fubini}{=}\int_0^\infty f_Y(y)\int_0^ydxdy\\
&=\int_0^\infty yf_Y(y)dy\\
&=\mathbb E[X]
\end{align*}

- Way 2 : The formula hold in a more general case than just being continuous :
  \begin{align*}
  \int_0^\infty \mathbb P(X>x)\,\mathrm d x&=\int_0^\infty \int_{\{X>x\}}d\mathbb Pdx\\
  &\underset{Fubini}{=}\int_\Omega  \int_0^{X(\omega )}dxd\mathbb P\\ &=\int_\Omega Xd\mathbb P\\
  &=\mathbb E[X].
  \end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Side note : your method and the standard solution given by Todd actually show that $x(1-F_{X}(x))\to 0$.

This may also be seen directly by dominated convergence theorem :

$$x 1_{X\geq x} \le X 1_{X\geq x} \le X$$

and

$$x 1_{X\geq x} \to 0 \text{ as } x \to \infty$$

imply

$$E[x 1_{X\geq x}]=x P(X\ge x) \to 0 $$

Nota bene : this beats by a little standard Markov inequality, that gives an effective bound, but not the $0$ limit, namely :

$$x P(X\ge x) \le E[X]$$

Answer (score 0):

This step
$$
\int_0^\infty 1\times(1-P(X\le x))dx=x(1-F_X(x))|_0^\infty+\int_0^\infty xf_X(x)dx 
$$
is not clear to me. I dont see what you did there, however if $f_X$ is the density of $X$ you have that
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{\infty }\Pr[X>t]\,\mathrm d t&=\int_0^{\infty }\int_t^{\infty }f_X(s)\,\mathrm d s \,\mathrm d t\\
&=\int_0^{\infty }\int_0^{\infty }\mathbf{1}_{A}(s,t)f_X(s)\,\mathrm d s\,\mathrm d t\\
&\overset{(*)}{=}\int_0^{\infty }\int_0^{\infty }\mathbf{1}_{A}(s,t)f_X(s)\,\mathrm d t\,\mathrm d s\\
&=\int_0^{\infty }f_X(s)\left(\int_0^\infty \mathbf{1}_{A}(s,t)\,\mathrm d t\right)\,\mathrm d s\\
&=\int_0^{\infty }f_X(s)\left(\int_0^s \,\mathrm d t\right)\,\mathrm d s\\
&=\int_0^{\infty }f_X(s)s \,\mathrm d s\\&=E[X]
\end{align*}
$$
where $A:=\{(s,t)\in \Bbb R ^2:0\leqslant t<s\}$, and where we used Tonelli's theorem in $\rm(*)$.

Comment: the above step I just did integration by parts