# How to prove the following result about CDFs?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, cumulative-distribution-functions

Suppose that $X$ is a non-negative rv with CDF $F$. Prove that for any $p \geq 1$, we have: 
$$\int_0^\infty x^p dF(x) = \int_0^\infty px^{p-1} (1-F(x)) dx$$

I tried to do this using integration by parts on the right integral, which gave me the result: 
$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} x^p(1-F(x)) + \int_0^\infty x^p dF(x) $$
but I am struggling to show that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} x^p(1-F(x)) = 0$. Could someone please provide some hints?

Also just wondering, how does the result change if $X$ is no longer non-negative?

Comment: Are you able to evaluate the simpler limits $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} x^p$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} (1-F(x))$?

Comment: I'm confused about it, because I know that 1-F(x) should approach 0 and x^p should approach infinity, but I am unsure about how I can use L'Hopitals rule to evaluate the limit of the product

Comment: It works similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3489882/321264. The result can be proved without integration by parts also.

Comment: That limit is either 0 (if X has finite $p$th moment) or else positive. When it is positive both sides are infinite.

Comment: That said the process is more easily handled by writing the right side as a double integral $dP dx$, changing the order of integration, and then doing the integral dx. Then just identify the remaining integral dP with the corresponding integral dF.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
x^pI(X>x)\leq X^{p}I(X>x)
$$
whence taking expectations of both sides
$$
x^pP(X>x)\leq E(X^{p}I(X>x))\to 0
$$
as $x\to \infty$ by the dominated convergence theorem assuming that $EX^p<\infty.$

Alternatively

Let $X$ be have distribution function $F$. Note that
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty px^{p-1} (1-F(x)) dx&=\int_0^\infty px^{p-1}\int_{\Omega} I(X>x)\, dP \, dx\\
&=\int_{\Omega}\int_0^Xpx^{p-1}\, dx\, dP\tag{0}\\
&=\int_{\Omega} X^{P} dP\\
&=EX^{p}\\
&=\int_{0}^\infty x^p\, dF(x)
\end{align*}
$$
where in (0) we used Tonelli's theorem.